# Including property files in compile targets

Tags: java, ant

I have a compilation ant target that looks like this:

```
  <target name="compile">
    <echo message="Compiling the java source files..."/>
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac compiler="modern"
           srcdir="${javasrc.dir}"
           destdir="${classes.dir}"
           debug="on"
           deprecation="off"
           failonerror="${haltonerror}" >
      <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </javac>
  </target>
```

Inside the javasrc.dir there may also be property files. For example Build.properties.

Is there away of including all of these property files where they belong in the classes dir that is populated by this target?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you simply copy them over.  Add this after the `javac` closing tag:

```
<copy todir="${classes.dir}">
  <fileset dir="${javasrc.dir}">
    <include name="**/*.properties" />
  </fileset>
</copy>
```

Comment: Does this work for all sub-directories(packages) of javasrc.dir?

Comment: Yes.  `**` matches any directory including sub directories, the `*.properties` matches any file name ending in `.properties`

Comment: I assume after they are all copied they will need to be relocated, there is no way to copy them to their corresponding directory location within classes.dir?

Comment: Nope, the directory structure is preserved.  You should be good to go.

Comment: That's quite powerful. Thanks a lot.